# What are the differences between 'incident', 'issue' and 'affair'?

Tags: differences, nouns

What are the difference between *incident, issue,* and *affair*? How should one use them?

Comment: These words are, to my mind, completely unrelated. What's the difference between *taxi*, *green*, and *kitchen*?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An *[incident](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/incident)* is a single distinct event - one occurrence of something that can happen more than once. It is often unpleasant and/or unexpected.

*[Issue](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/issue)* has lots of meanings. Given the other words you're asking about, the meanings you might be thinking of are (1) a problem, something that needs to be discussed/fixed; or (2) a topic of interest.

The first meaning that springs to mind for *[affair](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/search/affair)* is the extra-marital kind, but it can also mean a social event (of the dress-up kind), or a plain old (read: not sex related) scandal.

(I've linked each word to the definition with the most examples of usage that I could find.)

> After that incident with the neighbor's dog, 
>   he avoided chihuahuas like the plague.

vs.

> After that affair with the neighbor's dog, he 
>   avoided chihuahuas like the plague.

The *incident* probably took less time than the *affair* - for the former, I'd imagine the dog scared the man, while the latter might have involved an actual bite and subsequent lawyers and suits and animosity.

> After that issue with the neighbor's dog, he 
>   avoided chihuahuas like the plague.

Here the implication is that there was a problem which had (or should have had) a solution. I'd imagine the dog peed somewhere inappropriate, or something similar.

Comment: An affair could have issue: that is, give rise to offspring. This is, admittedly, a somewhat archaic usage.